# Chow variety of 1-cycles on abelian surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

It is an easy exercise to show that on a K3 surface, a smooth genus $g$ curve moves in a $g$-dimensional linear system.  Nearly the same exercise shows that on an abelian surface, the corresponding linear system is dimension $g-2$.  But you now also have a $2$-dimensional space of translations.  I'm wondering how these translations combine with the linear system to give the Chow variety of $1$-cycles.

For concreteness, let $A$ be an abelian surface over $\mathbb{C}$.  Fix an effective line bundle $L$ and corresponding linear system $|L| \cong \mathbb{P}^{g-2}$, all of whose elements are curves in the class $\beta \in H_{2}(A, \mathbb{Z})$.  Let $\text{Chow}_{\beta}(A)$ be the variety parameterizing algebraic 1-cycles with fixed homology class $\beta$.  Is it true that

$$\text{Chow}_{\beta}(A) \cong |L| \times A,$$

where a tuple $(C, a)$ represents the curve $t_{a}^{*}C$?  I'm thinking it can't quite be that simple because some curves in the linear system might be invariant under certain translations, right?  For example, if a curve $C \in |L|$ in invariant under translation $t_{a}$ by $a \in A$, then the points $(C, 0)$ and $(C, a)$ would be identified in the product.  Is the right answer a quotient of what I write in the equation above? Is there a concrete answer here?

I've been looking in the literature, and can't find anything on this.  I'd appreciate any help, and also sources if possible!

Comment: The situation for divisors on abelian surfaces is fully understood. Read Mumford's *Abelian varieties* for the behaviour of line bundles w.r.t. translations.

Comment: For a curve $C$ Mumford introduces the subgroup $H(C)$ of $A$ consisting of all $a \in A$ such that translation by $a$ preserves $C$ (as a curve, not just its class).  So is the idea that $\text{Chow}_{\beta}(A) = (|L| \times A)/\sim$ where $(C, a) \sim (C,b)$ if $a-b \in H(C)$?

Comment: It is not a product, but a projective bundle over $\operatorname{Pic}^{\beta }(A)\cong \hat{A} $, with fiber $|L|$ over $L\in \operatorname{Pic}^{\beta }(A)$.